# Checking for duplicate records in the database in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, shopify

This is my situation, I'm getting data from my Shopify shop via API and saving them to a database. My problem is how to prevent duplicate records from infesting the database. any code snippet about this? Thank you! i want only the new entries made from the shop to be saved instead of having all the entries enter the database over and over again.

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 2):

You can either add a `validates_uniqueness_of :field` in your model, or use a UNIQUE constraint in your database, or both.

The duplicate entries will raise an exception, which you can catch and ignore.

Comment: so if this is the data in my shop coming to my database: 1,2,3,4,5 and i add the value 6, (data is now 1,2,3,4,5,6) only 6 will be saved in my database? is that it? i'm having this error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

Comment: Each piece of data goes in one by one. If it violates a constraint, an exception should be thrown. Just ignore the exception and move on to the next record.

Comment: yes i think it violates the constraint that i did in the database that's why i'm having that error. So how can i make that exception and move on to the next record? the error keeps me from moving on. sorry i'm a rails newbie.

Comment: begin 
//your code here
rescue Exception => e 
//do nothing here
end

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to only grab records from Shopify that are new. For example, if you are syncing products, and the last product ID that you pulled down from your Shopify store is `12345`, then you can just hit the API for all the products that have an ID greater than `12345`:

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.all(params: {since_id: 12345})
```

Or you can record the last time you synced your products somewhere, like a `products_last_synced_at` field. The you can hit the Shopify API for records that have been updated since that last sync:

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.all(params: {updated_at_min: shop.products_last_synced_at})
```

Finally, I would use something like `Product.find_or_create_by_product_id(12345)` when updating your apps database, and using the `id` that comes from Shopify as the `product_id` attribute of your local `Product` model. This will make sure that each time you are syncing your orders, you are updating ones that have already been synced, and adding those that have not.

Of course, make sure to index the `product_id` column of your `products` table by putting the following into your migration:

```
add_index :products, :product_id, unique: true
```

This index will ensure that you cannot create product records with duplicate `product_id` values. If needed, for some weird edge case, you can always rescue for `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` errors and handle them as well.